# Error in Oracle query - unmatched parentheses after 20000+ lines of output

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I've resulted to exporting data from OpenText by database query and a LINUX copy. I'm having a issue with my query. I'm getting ORA-12725: unmatched parentheses in regular expression after about 20000 lines of output. Using TOAD, no errors in my code, but when it fails I get the Oracle error at line 62, which makes no sense. Please help if you can...

```
SELECT lpad(' ', LEVEL - 1)
    ,(
        CASE dtree.subtype
            WHEN 0
                THEN to_clob('mkdir -p ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(dtree.NAME, '/') || '''')
            WHEN 144 THEN (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'Default'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs01/livelink/discovery/filestore/'|| SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore02'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs21/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')                         
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore03'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs03/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'store04'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs04/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore05'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs05/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore06'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs06/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore07'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs07/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore08'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs08/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore09'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink01/discovery_fs09/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')                         
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore10'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs10/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore11'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs11/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore12'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs12/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore13'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs13/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore14'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs14/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore15'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs15/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore16'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs16/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore17'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink11/discovery_fs17/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore18'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs18/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore19'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs19/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore20'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs20/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore21'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs21/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore22'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs22/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore23'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs21/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                        WHEN providerdata.providertype = 'filestore24'
                            THEN to_clob('install -D /Net/livelink21/discovery_fs21/' || SUBSTR(providerdata.providerdata, INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) + 1, (INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 4) - INSTR(providerdata.providerdata, '''', 1, 3) - 1)) || ' ' || '''' || '/Net/livelink/util_mig/mig/Nexus_3383191' || regexp_replace(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), substr(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/'), - instr(reverse(sys_connect_by_path(dtree.NAME, '/')), '/') + 1), '') || dtree.dataid || '.v_' || dversdata.version || '.' || dversdata.filetype || '''')
                    ELSE null           
                        END
                    )
            END
        ) COPY
FROM dtree
LEFT OUTER JOIN dversdata ON (dtree.dataid = dversdata.docid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN providerdata ON (providerdata.providerid = dversdata.providerid)
START WITH dtree.dataid = & 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR dtree.dataid = dtree.parentid;
```

Comment: Could you just select ONLY the expression within the parentheses () of `REGEXP_REPLACE()` for ONE `WHEN` condition and post the result of that query?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why does it make no sense? One of the `dtree.name` values seems to have a parenthesis in it. Why are use using regexp for this instead of a regular replace; and why are you duplicating so much code?

Comment: The standard advice of doing everything in SQL that can be done in SQL has a limit, and that limit is maintainability. What you have here is a truly horrible piece of SQL. Wouldn't this be simpler and easier to maintain as a data-driven piece of PL/SQL?